# get columns with values from json

Tags: json, azure-data-explorer

Input JSON:

```
{"tags":{"timestampActual":"S","power":"W"},"items":[["1609598009","120"]]}
```

I need to convert it to columns using **Kusto** data language

| timestampActual | power |
| --- | --- |
| 1609598009 | 120 |

Or even convert unix timestamp value in seconds to UTC

| timestampActual | power |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-01-02T14:33:29 | 120 |

Answer (score 0):

Update it to take into account the key order:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[dynamic({"tags":{"timestampActual":"S","power":"W"},"items":[["1609598009","120"]]})]
| extend Keys = bag_keys(d.tags)
| mv-expand d.items
| extend Timestamp = unixtime_seconds_todatetime(tolong(d_items[array_index_of(Keys, "timestampActual")]))
| extend Power = toint(d_items[array_index_of(Keys, "power")])
| project-away d, d_items, Keys
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Generally yes, it does. The only question is how to substitute a tag with an item if the tag order is changed. Can you propose any solution? In my real-life example I have plenty of tags and the order can be different each time I get the data. The items always stored in the 1st array element in the same order as tags.

Comment: I updated the solution to get the items from the array based on the key position.

Comment: Pleasure! Can you please mark the answer?